# Mistake when substituting constraint $4x^2+y^2=1$ into a function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ in extrema problem

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Consider the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ under the constraint $4x^2+y^2=1$. The extrema of $f$ under that constraint can be easily found with Lagrange multipliers, and they are attained for $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$ for maximum and $(1/2,0)$, $(-1/2,0)$ for minimum; however, if we isolate $y^2=1-4x^2$ and we substitute it in the function, we get a wrong result (in particular, the one variable function $g(x)=1-3x^2$ obtained has only a maximum for $x=0$ and Weierstrass theorem assures that the are both maximum and minimum for $f$). Can someone explain me why this fails?

Comment: What's the domain of $g$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Hi, the domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are all the manipulations you have done valid for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: I'm not sure if the problem is this, but what you've said made me think about this: $x$ and $y$ are tied by the fact that $4x^2+y^2=1$, so we can't choose all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ but only the ones such that $x=-\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{4}}$ or $x=\sqrt{\frac{1-y^2}{4}}$.

Comment: That's the way I was thinking, and I think the key question is "For what range of $x$ values are we allowed to use $y^2 = 1-4x^2$?

Comment: Geometrically, your restriction means that the point belongs to an ellipse with horizontal semi-axis $1/2$, therefore $x\in[-1/2,1/2]$.

Comment: @GReyes - I think the original poster learns more when they get a chance to find the answer for themself.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC You are right. I was trying to give a different perspective, different from the purely algebraic one.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC: Thanks for your approach, I agree with you that it is better for learning. Well, $y^2=\sqrt{1-4x^2}\iff y=-\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ or $y=\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ so it must be $1-4x^2 \geq 0 \iff -\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$.
So this means that I must restrict $g$ to $-\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and then check by hand the values $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$ because derivatives only give information about extrema in $-\frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Gwyn: Bingo, you got it!

Comment: There is still a problem. When you replace $y^2$ in the function $f(x,y)$, you get $f(x)=1-3x^2$ as you correctly noted. Now in $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, it is obvious that $f(x,y)$ cannot be negative. However, $f(x)=1-3x^2$ CAN become negative, hence we need to restrict $x$ between $-1/\sqrt{3}$and $1/\sqrt{3}$, which captures your minima of $x=-0.5$ and $x=0.5$, but you didn't find those by investigating $1-3x^2$.. How come?

Comment: @imranfat: Thanks for your comment, maybe I'm missing something but since $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < -\frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ applying the condition seen before the positivity of $g$ is automatically implicated.

Answer (score 1):

Solving

$$
\min_{x,y}(\max_{x,y})(x^2+y^2)\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ 4x^2+y^2=1
$$

using the Lagrange multipliers method, reduces to determine the stationary points for

$$
\nabla(x^2+y^2)+\lambda\nabla(4x^2+y^2-1)=0
$$

by solving for $x,y,\lambda$

$$
\cases{
2x+8x\lambda=0\\
2y+2y\lambda=0\\
4x^2+y^2-1=0
}
$$

giving as solutions the four tangency points between the level curves for $z=x^2+y^2$ and the ellipse $4x^2+y^2-1=0$. Those points can be depicted in the attached plot.

[image]

Now by making the substitution $y = 1-4x^2$ into $z = x^2+y^2$ giving $z=1-3x^2$ we are searching extrema along the $x$ axis at $x^*=0$ with value $1$ and the corresponding $y^*$ we obtain from the restriction $4(x^*)+(y^*)^2=1$.   Also with the substitution $x^2=\frac{1-y^2}{4}$ we are searching extrema along the $y$ axis with value $\frac 14$.